Jetpack Compose Accessibility ClickableText vs BasicText with modifier.clickable
To enhance accessibility, I aim to make links within a “Terms and Privacy Policy” paragraph navigable via external keyboard input. Initially, I encountered challenges getting the focus behavior I want by applying the focusable modifier to ClickableText components. I explored an alternative solution by combining BasicText with the Modifier.clickable() (recognizing that ClickableText internally relies on a BasicText component). While this combined approach functions as expected, I’m curious about any potential differences in "click behavior" compared to using ClickableText directly, particularly from an accessibility standpoint.
Thanks
Some code for reference:
ClickableText(
        modifier = modifier,
        text = annotatedString,
        style = TextStyle(
            color = Grey,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        ),
        onClick = { offset ->
            annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(start = offset, end = offset)
                .firstOrNull()?.let { annotation ->
                    uriHandler.openUri(annotation.item)
                }
        }
    )

            BasicText(
                text = privacyPolicy.toAnnotatedString(
                    TextStyleData(
                        text = privacyPolicy,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                        textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline,
                        clickable = true
                    )
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable { uriHandler.openUri(privacyUri) }
            )


Could you please share your code so that folks can evaluate it? Otherwise all that can be done is guess

@QuintinB Sure thing! Added some code for reference

Unfortunately, this solution does not work when you have multiple links in the text. I ended up with copying the ClickableText component that is looking up the item at the position where the user tapped.
